# Post request and get response robotframework

Tags: json, post, httpresponse, robotframework

I need to send POST request and get json from it.

```
  Create Http Context    emopstest.pdc.org    http
    Set Request Header    Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Set Request Header    Authorization    Basic bG9naW46cGFzcw==
    ${dict}=    Create Dictionary    app_ids=18    where=ROWNUM<=2000
    ${value}=    Stringify Json    ${dict}
    Set Request Body    ${value}
    HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    /auth_srv/services/auth/1/json/get_hazards
    Show Response Body In Browser
    Response Status Code Should Equal    200
    ${result_text}=    Get Response Body
    ${result_json}=    Parse Json    ${result_text}
```

But this code returns to me 404...
What is wrong?

Comment: It's hard to advise too much as we don't know much about what you're working with.  As you know a 404 means not found, your POST isn't successful.  Is the URL definitely correct?  Are your headers working and correct?  When you perform the same request using the likes of POSTMAN or DHC,does it succeed?  What errors were returned?  What keywords failed and what did it return?

Answer (score 0):

The 404 means that the server couldn't find the resource you requested. Usually that means the URL was wrong. Depending on how the server is configured, it could also mean that your authorization is wrong (ie: some applications will give a 404 in the case of bad authentication, so that an attacker isn't given a clue that the credentials are incorrect)

The server logs should have information that will help you track down whether you have an incorrect URL or that the server has a bug.